# How to calculate Total transactions amount column with input / output type?

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables : (transactions and Accounts) their columns are as shown in the picture bellow:

the Accounts table is simple just two columns ID and account name.

The important columns in the Transactions table are Amount and type, the type indicates whether the transaction is an input to the account or an output.

I want to find the current total amount **(input - output)** for each account with SQL.

**this what I have tried but I couldn't go further:**

```
select c.TRS_AC_ID, CompAccount, sum(Amount), Type from Accounts c 
INNER JOIN Transactions t on c.TRS_AC_ID = t.TRS_AC_ID GROUP by CompAccount, Type
```

[image]

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of grouping by the `type`, you could use a `case` expression to return "input" transactions as is and "output" transactions as negative numbers:

```sql
SELECT   c.TRS_AC_ID, CompAccount, SUM(CASE type WHEN 'O' THEN -1 * amount ELSE amount END)
FROM     Accounts c 
JOIN     Transactions t on c.TRS_AC_ID = t.TRS_AC_ID
GROUP BY c.TRS_AC_ID, CompAccount
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following SQL to get the result of input-output, however, if you need individual results then you can use either sub-query as well.

```
select
    (select sum(amount) as input from transaction
    where trs_ac_id = '1' and type_io = 'I'))
    -
    (seelect sum(amount) as output from transaction
    where trs_ac_id = '2' and type_io = 'O')) as current_tot_amt
from dual;
```